# how can i email junit test result from jenkins in tabular form?

Tags: jenkins, testing, junit, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am unable to email junit test result from jenkins. I  want to send it in a tabular form. currently i send it but the design is not good in email.

I have already tried multiple techniques but the report is not as good as I want. like junit2html etc.

i am using free style jenkins project.
can any one please tell me how can i send the "Test result" table from jenkins to my personal email.

below is code in my custom python builder

```
   py.test --junitxml report.xml
```